# How to activate java swing application by keystroke when it's in system tray

Tags: java, swing

I want to show the form when someone presses a key in my java swing application when it is in system tray. I have tried adding key listeners, but it didn't work. I know this can be done by using Popup menu. But I want to know can java swing app can detect keystrokes when it is in system tray? can anyone help me to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You might look at JIntelliType (http://melloware.com/products/jintellitype/index.html) but this will only be a windows solution. There may be something similar for other OSes. This library provides global hotkey registration which is what you need.

Update: looks like they reference a similar API for linux also.

Comment: This is correct.  Jintellitype does exactly this but is Windows only since it uses the Windows native API to accomplish this.  JxGrabKey is a similar library available for Linux.  As far as I know there is still now Mac OSX solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JNI to hook into Window's Window-Event-API, i think, but this is complicated. A more simple but slightly hacky way to do it is create a link in the Start>>Programs menu, set a key-combination there, then with that link call your program into windowed-mode or fullscreen-mode.

Comment: JIntelliType does this... see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no, it's not possible.

See [Is it Possible to show a previously hidden JFrame using a keylistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844619/is-it-possible-to-show-a-previously-hidden-jframe-using-a-keylistener)