# How to add a key listener to a tray

Tags: java, awt, keylistener, system-tray

So I have a system tray class and I was wondering if there was anyway I can add a key listener to it so that when the user runs the program it'll be minimized in the tray and when they press a key combinations (that they set in the program settings) the program will do something.

Comment: It's possible but I believe requires using non-Java tools such as AutoHotKey or AutoIt if run in a Windows environment and similar tools for other platforms. Another route would be via JNI or JNA. Of course any of these solutions will necessarily be platform dependent.

Comment: Is there anyway I can make a JFrame have a opacity of 0 and so that the user can click through it?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2844657/1196670) is discusion on same theme - it's not possible because when you make the app invisible, it stops recieving input events. It's based on operating system, it's not your application.